# Create bi-weekly and monthly labels with week numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, week-number

I have a dataframe with profit values, IDs, and week values. It looks a little like this

| ID | Week | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 0 |
| A | 4 | 0 |

I want to create two new columns called "Bi-Weekly" and "Monthly", so week 1 would be label 2, week 2 would also be label 2, but week 3 would be labeled 4, and week 4 would be labeled 4, and they would all be labeled month 1, so I could groupby weekly, bi-weekly, or monthly profit as needed. Right now I've created two functions which work, but the weeks are going to go up to a year (52 weeks) so I was wondering if there's a more efficient way. My  bi-weekly function below.

```
def biweek(prof_calc):
    if (prof_calc['week']==2):
        return 2
    elif (prof_calc['week']==3):
        return 2
    elif (prof_calc['week']==4):
        return 4
    elif (prof_calc['week']==5):
        return 4
    elif (prof_calc['week']==6):
        return 6
    elif (prof_calc['week']==7):
        return 6
    elif (prof_calc['week']==8):
        return 8
    elif (prof_calc['week']==9):
        return 8
    elif (prof_calc['week']==10):
        return 10
    elif (prof_calc['week']==11):
        return 10
    
prof_calc['BiWeek'] = prof_calc.apply(biweek, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could try:

```
df["Biweekly"] = (df["Week"]-1)//2+1
df["Monthly"] = (df["Week"]-1)//4+1

>>> df
   ID  Week  Profit  Biweekly  Monthly
0   A     1      42         1        1
1   A     2      69         1        1
2   A     3      53         2        1
3   A     4      63         2        1
4   A     5      56         3        2
5   A     6      57         3        2
6   A     7      86         4        2
7   A     8      23         4        2
8   A     9      35         5        3
9   A    10      10         5        3
10  A    11      25         6        3
11  A    12      21         6        3
12  A    13      39         7        4
13  A    14      82         7        4
14  A    15      76         8        4
15  A    16      20         8        4
16  A    17      97         9        5
17  A    18      67         9        5
18  A    19      21        10        5
19  A    20      22        10        5
20  A    21      88        11        6
21  A    22      67        11        6
22  A    23      33        12        6
23  A    24      38        12        6
24  A    25       8        13        7
25  A    26      67        13        7
26  A    27      16        14        7
27  A    28      49        14        7
28  A    29       3        15        8
29  A    30      17        15        8
30  A    31      79        16        8
31  A    32      19        16        8
32  A    33      21        17        9
33  A    34       9        17        9
34  A    35      56        18        9
35  A    36      83        18        9
36  A    37       1        19       10
37  A    38      53        19       10
38  A    39      66        20       10
39  A    40      55        20       10
40  A    41      85        21       11
41  A    42      90        21       11
42  A    43      34        22       11
43  A    44       3        22       11
44  A    45       9        23       12
45  A    46      28        23       12
46  A    47      58        24       12
47  A    48      14        24       12
48  A    49      42        25       13
49  A    50      69        25       13
50  A    51      76        26       13
51  A    52      49        26       13
```